# Address Word Structure

Tags: computer-architecture

In Vol. 1 Issue 1, Jan. 1958 of the magazine *Communications of the ACM*, Dr. Saul Gorn discusses the advantages of the computer architecture of Edvac to that of Eniac.

He states that the Edvac had a **three-plus-one address word structure**, and that the tendencies of his time period were to use **one-address hardware** and **three-plus-zero address pseudo-codes**. He then goes on to say that for the future he imagines using variable instruction-word-length machines.

My questions: What is a **three-plus-one address word structure**? What is a **one-address hardware** and **three-plus-zero address pseudo code**? What do these terms mean exactly? I understand what a word is, but not to an extent that would allow me to understand these terms contextually.

Link to this issue of CACM: [here](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=368685&CFID=736097678&CFTOKEN=55088797). I believe an ACM membership is required to access the magazine. This question refers to Dr. Saul Gorn's Letter to the Editor.

Comment: I would guess that it is referring to three source operand addresses plus one destination address. One address hardware would presumably be accumulator-based. "Plus zero" probably refers to an implicit destination address (one of the sources, a fixed address [e.g., stack and accumulator architectures], or opcode-dependent address). "Pseudo code" probably refers to a quasi-assembly language used by programmers which can be trivially translated into actual machine assembly/code. (This is a comment because it is speculation.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The EDVAC employed a 44 bit word with a 4 bit op code and 4 10 bit address fields.

While the use of the fields varied a lot, the ADD instruction was typical. The memory location in field 1 was added to the memory location in field 2 and the result placed into the memory location in field 3. Execution of code then continued at the location addressed by field 4.

Thus we can summarize C = A + B; GOTO D

As for simulation with pseudo codes, we can deduce that for the Accumulator + One address machines popular at the time, the C = A + B would be simulated with three instructions and the GOTO part would be omitted. Thus three-plus-zero. It might look something like (stylized not actual code):

```
; ADD A,B,C
LD Acc, A
ADD Acc, B
ST Acc, C
```

For more on EDVAC please see:

https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015002095639;view=1up;seq=87